# Rails 3.2.x app not writing a log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant figure out why my rails app is not generating the log file any more. I restarted the web server but still no sign of the log file. What config parameters could possible make it not being generated?

Comment: Add the command line output of starting rails... not the log one, the one that appears when you run `rails server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the folder `log`? Does the user that runs rails have write permissions on the folder?

Comment: I cant believe it, somehow my deployment script was changed, yes the log folder had the wrong permissions. That did it